# How to read a simple graphml file in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4J desktop and its really hard to find any proper documentation. I have a simple graphml that I would to read into Neo4J. Does someone know a simple step-by-step guide for this?

I cant even run commands in the browser, because it wants me to connect to a database - I just want to read from a simple file?

Comment: Have you tried https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/import/graphml/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've setup up a project with a Database Management System (DBMS) and a local database.

After that you need to install a plugin called [APOC](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/) it provides neo4j with additional functionality i.e. to import .graphml files. This can be done by clicking on the DBMS (No button, just the cell) and selecting 'Plugins' on the right tabs, see [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDKDp.png)
Then create  or modify the `apoc.conf` file in the conf folder which you can access by starting the DBMS of your database and on the top where is shows Active DBMS select the three dots on the right to and select 'Open Folder' and 'Configuration', see [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqTD5.png)
**Make sure** the line `apoc.import.file.enabled=true` is in the `apoc.conf` file.
Now open another folder, following the same steps as above but choosing 'Import' instead. Place your .graphml file here which you would like to read.
Finally restart the DBMS, open the Neo4jBrowser and type the following command in the top row: `CALL apoc.import.graphml("file://YOURFILE.graphml", {})` and replace YOURFILE.

That's it, for further reading I would recommend the [APOC Import Graphml docs](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/graphml/)